# Control Complex Sprite Image as a car Configurator

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm doing a personal proyect where the user can configurate their car online. The basis is simple: 3 buttons (Change Color - Change View - Lights On/Off) and the following sprite image:

[image: Ford Sprite]

As you can see, the user can choose between 3 colors, change the view and turn the lights on.

So far so good, the problem is making this to reality, this is what I've got so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#color").click(function(){
        $('#box').toggleClass('white-front-off');
    });
    $("#view").click(function(){
        $('#box').toggleClass('red-back-off');
    });
    $("#lights").click(function(){
        $('#box').toggleClass('red-front-on');
    });
});
```

```css
#box{
  width: 113px;
  height: 85px;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNsgN.jpg);
}

.red-front-off {
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.red-back-off {
  background-position: -226px 0px;
}

.red-front-on {
  background-position: -113px 0px;
}

.red-back-on {
  background-position: -339px 0px;
}

.white-front-off {
  background-position: 0px -85px;
}

.white-back-off {
  background-position: -226px -85px;
}

.white-front-on {
  background-position: -113px -85px;
}

.white-back-on {
  background-position: -339px -85px;
}

.black-front-off {
  background-position: 0px -85px;
}

.black-back-off {
  background-position: -226px -85px;
}

.black-front-on {
  background-position: -113px -85px;
}

.black-back-on {
  background-position: -339px -85px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box" class="red-front-off"></div>
<button id="color">Change Color</button>
<button id="view">Change View</button>
<button id="lights">Lights On/Off</button>
```

I'm new to sprites and JQuery so I did my best. These are the following issues:

1 - I don't know how to "add" values in Jquery (imagine color red is 0, white is 1 and black is 2, I know how to toggle between 0 and 1, but I don't know how to reach the 2) in the snippet you can see that I can't see the black color.

2 - If the user clicks "change color" and the last color (in this case black) is on the viewport, somehow the sprite must start again with the red color (This might be possible with background repeat, so I didn't change that).

3 - If the user clicks "Lights On/Off" no matter what color or view, the lights must turn on/off in the correct position.

This is a huge project for me, so any help is more than acceptable and I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's make a state and use that to render what the view should be

(BTW your CSS for black was off in the Y direction)

```js
var colorMap = ['red', 'white', 'black'];
function renderState(state){
  var classString = colorMap[state.color];
  classString += (state.front) ? '-front' : '-back';
  classString += (state.lights) ? '-on' : '-off';
  
  $("#box").removeClass();
  $("#box").addClass(classString);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    var state = {
      color: 0,
      front: true,
      lights: false,
    }
    renderState(state);
    $("#color").click(function(){
      state.color++;
      state.color %=3;
      renderState(state);
    });
    $("#view").click(function(){
        state.front = !state.front;
        renderState(state);
        
    });
    $("#lights").click(function(){
        state.lights = !state.lights;
        renderState(state);
    });
});
```

```css
#box{
  width: 113px;
  height: 85px;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNsgN.jpg);
}

.red-front-off {
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.red-back-off {
  background-position: -226px 0px;
}

.red-front-on {
  background-position: -113px 0px;
}

.red-back-on {
  background-position: -339px 0px;
}

.white-front-off {
  background-position: 0px -85px;
}

.white-back-off {
  background-position: -226px -85px;
}

.white-front-on {
  background-position: -113px -85px;
}

.white-back-on {
  background-position: -339px -85px;
}

.black-front-off {
  background-position: 0px -170px;
}

.black-back-off {
  background-position: -226px -170px;
}

.black-front-on {
  background-position: -113px -170px;
}

.black-back-on {
  background-position: -339px -170px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box" class="red-front-off"></div>
<button id="color">Change Color</button>
<button id="view">Change View</button>
<button id="lights">Lights On/Off</button>
```

Comment: @Ermac Thanks. It was a fun one.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I'm late to the party but stumbled upon this question and just could not resist to tell you:
*no need to mess with huge amounts of CSS and JS*...

#### all you need is math

If you know that **one sprite** is **113×85 px** in a **4×3 grid**:

```js
var w = 113, h = 85, x = 0, y = 0; // Sprite size and position

$("#color, #view, #lights").click(function() {

  if (this.id === "color")  y -= h;
  if (this.id === "view")   x -= w * 2;
  if (this.id === "lights") x -= (this.dataset.IO ^= 1) ? w : -w;

  x %= w * 4; // Reset to 0 if out of bounds so we can loop
  y %= h * 3;

  $("#box").css({backgroundPosition: x +'px '+ y +'px'});

});
```

```css
#box {
  width: 113px;
  height: 85px;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNsgN.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>
<button id="color">Change Color</button>
<button id="view">Change View</button>
<button id="lights">Lights On/Off</button>
```